# Identification menu bar android

Tags: android

What is the menu? The is PopupMenu or PopupWindow? 
What is it menu PopupWindow or what? I can not understand help me please.

[Image Photo Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19qd7.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Menu - What is it PopupWindow or what?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34100084/menu-what-is-it-popupwindow-or-what)

Answer (score 0):

A **PopupMenu** displays a Menu in a modal popup window anchored to a View. The popup will appear below the anchor view if there is room, or above it if there is not. If the IME is visible the popup will not overlap it until it is touched. Touching outside of the popup will dismiss it.

**A popup window** that can be used to display an arbitrary view. The popup window is a floating container that appears on top of the current activity.